# How to get like status from Facebook JS SDK

Tags: facebook

I'd like to know if it's possible to get `like status` within my Facebook app (**iframe**) using FB JS SDK.

What I want is the below but in JS.

```
<?php require 'lib/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook( array( 
  'appId'   => APP_ID,
  'secret'  => APP_SECRET,
  'cookie'  => true
) );

try {
  $me = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch ( FacebookApiException $e ) {
  error_log( $e );
}

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$liked = $signed_request['page']['liked'];

?>

<?php
if ( $liked ) : ?>
  YOU LIKE US!
<?php else : ?>
  YOU DON'T LIKE US YET!
<?php endif; ?>

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var session = FB.getSession();
FB.api(
    {
        method: 'fql.query',
        query: 'SELECT uid, page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=' + session.uid + ' AND page_id=YOUR_APP_ID'
    },
    function(response) {
        if(response instanceof Array && response.length > 0)
            alert("YOU LIKE US!");
        else
            alert("YOU DON'T LIKE US YET!");
    }
);
```

Comment: See updated code. It assumes that the user is logged in and connected.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code. Is it possible to remove the requirement for a user to be connected? This is a fan page which doesn't require people to "connect".

Comment: If you want user data - then that user needs to be connected. If connection is not an option then you would be better off using your PHP solution.

Comment: Well thats nice, but what now since fql is more or less outdated?